# AngularJS google maps directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-google-maps

I'm trying to develop an app using angularjs and a directive that I've found for instantiate GMaps: http://nlaplante.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/usage. I follow all the steps but I cant get to render the map! it returns no errors!

in the HTML

```
<html ng-app="Maptesting">
```

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

```
<script src="app/map.js">
</script>
```

In the controller:

```
angular.module('Maptesting', ['google-maps'])

.controller('CtrlGMap', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.center = {
            latitude: 45,
            longitude: -73
        };

        $scope.markers = [];
        $scope.zoom = 8;

}])
```

Comment: are you loading lodash.underscore.js ? It seems you need that script, though it should throw an error if you don't have it. [info here](http://angular-google-maps.org/use)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different answer, but I felt google-maps-directive is harder for me to use. Thus, I have created a [google maps angularjs directive](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) called, ng-map for my own project. This does not require any Javascript coding for simple functionality.

it looks like this

```
<map zoom="11" center="[40.74, -74.18]">
  <marker position="[40.74, -74.18]" />
  <shape name="circle" radius="400" center="[40.74,-74.18]" radius="4000" />
  <control name="overviewMap" opened="true" />
</map>
```

Comment: How to change center dynamically

Comment: @AshishNautiyal `center="{{dynamicCenter}}"` can do

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem. The solution was to ensure that in your CSS you include a height value for the 'angular-google-map-container' class. You don't have to add this class to your HTML; it is already included in the Javascript for the angular-google-maps directive. **Adding the height as an inline style will not work** because this specific class is added added through transclusion within the directive.

```
.angular-google-maps-container {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use `refresh="!isMapElementHidden"`?
It should work if you remove these property.

http://embed.plnkr.co/p9rXdx1GnmnuLKsEAMkE/preview

**angular.js:**

```
angular.module('Maptesting', ['google-maps'])

.controller('CtrlGMap', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.center = {
            latitude: 45,
            longitude: -73
        };

        $scope.markers = [];
        $scope.zoom = 8;

}])
```

**index.html:**

```
<html ng-app="Maptesting">
<body ng-controller="CtrlGMap">
<google-map center="center" 
            zoom="zoom" 
            markers="markers" 
            style="height: 400px; width: 100%; display: block;">
</google-map>

<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As zewt112 already mentioned, it can be resolved by adding

```
.angular-google-map-container {
    height: 400px;
}
```

But beware that in latest version class name is exactly angular-google-**map**-container and not angular-google-**maps**-container